# G-code to cartesian co-ordinate converter

Tags: arduino, python

Hope you all are doing well.

So I built a 5 bar linkage mechanism using arduino and python.It uses 2 servos, an arduino mega, a 12v power supply,a dc-dc step down converter to power everything.
The arduino's job is to to take two angle input in a csv format via usb serial input and rotate the servos to that specific angle.
The python script's job is to take a xy input in csv format via terminal and calculate the two angles using inverse kinematics so that the end-effector reaches the desired xy position and send them to the arduino via serial.

I have been seeing a lot of pen plotter videos recently and saw almost all of them use grbl and universal g code sender.
What i want to do - use g codes to with my python script to plot figures.(I dont care about accuracy,i just want to see some plots :]).

So is there any scripts or something related which takes G-codes as input and outputs XYZ position of the toolpath in correect sequences so that
I can just input those sequences in my python code to get the plots hopefully?

Comment: if i understand you correctly, you want to take XYZ position data, convert it to G-code, transmit the G-code, then convert the G-code to XYZ position data ... is my understanding correct?

Comment: I only want to turn g-code data  into XYZ position- like this guy is trying to do [link](https://www.cnczone.com/forums/uncategorised-cam-discussion/260616-cam-software.html) @jsotola